# How to query in firebase in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure in firebase

```
{
 "users":{
"Arshak Anjum": {
    "UserName": "Arshak Anjum",
    "admin": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "UserId": 959125570900519
 } 
 }
 }
```

I want to query the database and load the page only if the status of that person is 0.
How do I set up a reference to users and query by name.
I want to query "Select * from users where id="Arshak Anjum" AND status=1;"
I am using react

```
var userRef = database.ref('/users/'+authData.displayName);
var user=userRef.where("status","==",1)
```

This code doesn't work. I am a beginner in firebase.
Also how do i update the status to 1 after some operations.

Answer (score 5):

The code you have show the query syntax for Cloud Firestore, which is not compatible with the Firebase Realtime Database. To query the latter, use the methods mentioned in its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). For example:

```
var userRef = database.ref('/users/'+authData.displayName);
var userQuery = userRef.orderByChild("status").equalTo(1);
userQuery.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key, child.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code you provided doesn't work and returns null as snapshot.

Comment: It probably returns null because there is no object with status set to 1 @ArshakAnjum

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Then it would be an empty snapshot but not `null`. Calling `forEach` on `null` throws an error.

Comment: The documentation says that `once()` returns a `Promise`. Shouldn't it be `userQuery.once(...).then(snapshot => {...})`?

Comment: `once()` returns a promise, but also invokes a classic callback. I used the latter in this answer, since it's closest to the syntax you'd use for `on()` (which doesn't return a promise, since it may "resolve" multiple times).

Comment: @trixn: for your earlier comment: the callback is *never* invoked with `null`. An empty snapshot is possible if there is no value at the location, but the client will never pass `null`, hence `snapshot.forEach()` is a safe operation.

Comment: @ArshakAnjum Please edit your question to show what you've tried based on the code I provided. As Rosário says, it is most likely that there is no data at the location that `userRef` points to, or it doesn't follow the structure that I expected from reading your code. The only way to solve that is if you also provide a snippet of the JSON at `userRef` in your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know that it's a safe operation and the snapshot is never `null` in the callback. But Rosario said that "It probably returns null because there is no object with status set to 1" when OP said that snapshot is null. I responded to that. Read the comment history carefully.