# In react, how do I redirect back the to current page I'm on and include a url parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm still working on my react skills and am having a struggle with redirecting back to THE CURRENT "page" (component/control) that I'm on. Below is some sample code of what I have in my app.js file and then a snippet of what I have in my "PageTwo.js" file. Currently when I click on the checkbox icon, the page appears to redirect but none of my table data shows or a different way to say it maybe is that my table control doesn't reload. Any help would be appreciated.

app.js

```
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/PageTwo" exact component={PageTwo} />
          <Route path="/PageThree/:id" exact component={PageThree} />
        </Switch>
```

PageTwo.js

```
.
.
.
    const myRedirect = (stdId) => {
        history.push('/PageTwo/' + stdId);
    }
.
.
.
    useEffect(() => {
        let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/studentTime');
        var refQuery = ref.orderByChild("TimeOut").equalTo("");

        refQuery.on("value", studentTimeLog => {
            theTimeLogList = O2A(studentTimeLog);
            getTheTimeLog(theTimeLogList);
        });
        
        let userRef = Firebase.database().ref('/users');
        var userQuery = userRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(authContext.userEmail);
        //console.log(userQuery);
        userQuery.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                if (child.val().Role === "ADMIN") {
                    authContext.isAdmin = true;
                    console.log(authContext.isAdmin);
                }
            });
        });
    }, []);

.
.
.
                                <TableCell align="center">
                                    <CheckIcon onClick={() =>myRedirect(row.StudentId)}/>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
```

[image: Before clicking the check icon]

[image: After clicking the check icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your router.

```
<Route path="/PageTwo" exact component={PageTwo} />
<Route path="/PageThree/:id" exact component={PageThree} />

const myRedirect = (stdId) => {
  history.push('/PageTwo/' + stdId);
}

If you mean PageTree, follow this method.
<Route path="/PageThree/:id" exact component={PageThree} />
   . . .
const [stdId, setStdId] = useState('');
const myRedirect = () => {
  history.push('/PageThree/' + stdId);
}
```

or
use window.location.reload(); instead of history.push()

Comment: I do mean to return to page PageTwo.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Route` for page 2 is `exact` it will only show if it is exactly the correct url so when you add parameters, it's no longer exactly that. Simply remove the `exact` keyword and it should work.

Comment: I will try this tonight or in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this just not and the URL route itself does change, but I was expecting it to also hit my useEffect() method as well. Why does this not happen?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do. Well let me say it this way, I found ***A WAY***.

If I add the current URL to the 2nd optional array argument, then it will hit my useEffect() again as I desire. Let me say right off the bat that I'm not 100% sure this is ***THE BEST WAY*** to do this but it does fit my immediate need/desire to make sure that my useEffect() is hit if the url changes. It works for what I'm looking for because it re-renders my grid/table, which is what I want. If there is a better way to achieve this then I'm completely open to learning that. My main goal was for this page to "re-render" my control while getting the new URL (with my parameter added to it).

my app.js Switch/Route code

```
    <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/PageTwo/:stdid?" component={PageTwo} />
    <Route path="/PageThree/:id" exact component={PageThree} />
    </Switch>
```

my new useEffect()

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/studentTime');
        var refQuery = ref.orderByChild("TimeOut").equalTo("");

        refQuery.on("value", studentTimeLog => {
            theTimeLogList = O2A(studentTimeLog);
            getTheTimeLog(theTimeLogList);
        });
        
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240734/how-to-query-in-firebase-in-react
        let userRef = Firebase.database().ref('/users');
        var userQuery = userRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(authContext.userEmail);
        //console.log(userQuery);
        userQuery.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                if (child.val().Role === "ADMIN") {
                    authContext.isAdmin = true;
                    console.log(authContext.isAdmin);
                }
            });
        });
    }, [window.location.href]);
```